# In Gliffy how do you add connection points to a shape?

Tags: gliffy

How do you add connection points to a Gliffy diagram's shape? I fear the answer is that you cannot. Do you know otherwise?

I've dropped a "database" shape on my diagram but it has only a single connection point on either side (and some on top/bottom). I need more but I cannot figure out how to add them.

I've 'riffled through' the online help but all I can find is that ["certain shapes..." have infinite connection points](https://guide.gliffy.com/user-manual/gliffy-online-user-manual/1/en/topic/infinite-connection-points). Apparently the "database" shape is not one of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to add new connection points, so instead I resorted to putting another shape (with the connection points I needed in the right place) underneath my original shape and grouping the two shapes together!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you actually need to add special connection points (like in Visio).  Just zoom in to the object you want to connect line to and place the connector end on/near the shape edge you want to connect to. The end will change to a blue/green 'donut' blob which means it is hard-connected to the edge.  Release the mouse button and the line will be connected to the shape edge so you can move the shape around and the line end will follow.

Alternatively, you can group several shapes together after aligning and resizing them so the connector points of each shape are visible. E.g. a circle can be rotated 15 degrees at a time so you get 24 connection points.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This method was tested on Basic Shapes/Circle and Flowchart/Database shapes, but appears to work for any shape.

1. Start a Gliffy diagram
2. More Shapes (bottom left panel)
3. Flowchart
4. Drag Database shape onto the canvas
5. Disable (toggle) Show Grid (top toolbar, right)
6. Screen capture the shape making sure to get as close to shape boundaries as possible.  Or crop the image to shape boundaries using an image editor.
7. Save the captured shape in SVG format if possible, otherwise a format that preserves lines such as PNG is desirable.
8. More Shapes again
9. Add Custom Library
10. Drag/Drop/Upload captured shape
11. Give your library a name, hit enter to complete
12. Save Library, it appears in the shapes panel, Okay
13. Drag your custom shape to the canvas
14. Enable (toggle) Connector Tool
15. The Database shape now has 3 connection points per side, and accepts text as with any shape

Things to keep in mind

- Leaving a buffer around your captured shape will extend connection points outside your shape.  If you want them on the shape boundary, crop tightly.
- Use SVG format for your captured shape to have it smoothly render and scale in Gliffy.
- Finally this method was created out of desperation on a hunch without Google or Gliffy guidance.  Thus it might or might not work in the future as it's essentially an undocumented feature.